# How to install a Sublime Text 3 theme?

Tags: sublime-text-2, themes, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I don't understand why I'm getting all these errors:

```
Error loading colour scheme Packages/Material Theme/schemes/Material-Theme.tmTheme:
Unable to open Packages/Material Theme/schemes/Material-Theme.tmTheme
```

[image]

I've followed the super simple instructions here to install the Material Design theme: https://github.com/equinusocio/material-theme

Same problem with SpaceGray: https://github.com/kkga/spacegray

My user settings file in Sublime Text

```
{
    "always_show_minimap_viewport": true,
    "bold_folder_labels": true,
    "theme": "Material-Theme.sublime-theme",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Material Theme/schemes/Material-Theme.tmTheme",
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "line_padding_bottom": 3,
    "line_padding_top": 3,
    "overlay_scroll_bars": "enabled",
    "rulers":
    [
        80
    ],
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "word_separators": "./\\()\"':,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?",
    "word_wrap": true
}
```

The following is where my **Browse Packages** command opens up:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had my computer reformatted so just recently install Sublime Text 3 again, I thought just copying over my packages would have worked.

But I was wrong, PackageControl doesn't come standard with Sublime Text (which is super strange to me) so you have to install it manually here, then you can just install the package via it's internal command `Command + P`

https://packagecontrol.io/installation

Comment: If this is resolved you should select the answer